# using Amplify with svelte-kit getting tslib error on build

Tags: aws-amplify, sveltekit

I'm trying to use aws-amplify with svelte-kit and adapter-static, but I get this build error:

```
> Using @sveltejs/adapter-static
> The requested module 'tslib' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

this comes from `npm run build` when using `adapter-static`

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into a similar issues with sveltekit. I'm not too sure if it's coming from sveltekit, vite, or tslib but it seems to be a bug coming from one of these.

I run this script pre-build and it seems to fix the issues for me.

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

try {
  const filePath = path.resolve('./node_modules/tslib/modules/index.js')
  console.log('fixing tslib export', filePath)
  let file = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8')
  if (!file.includes('export default tslib')) {
    file += '\nexport default tslib;\n'
  }
  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, file)
} catch (err) {
  console.error('error: fixing tslib export', err)
}
```

There's more info [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/tslib/issues/143) if you need